# Properties of View Objects / State Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uiview, uicolor

I recently came across some behavior concerning views when I tried to setup a "theme" class as a singleton that basically functioned as a theme/stylesheet for my whole apps colors.  Every view was assigned colors that were properties of the theme object.  So I would setup a view's color like:  `someDetailView.backgroundColor = [Theme SharedTheme].detailViewsBackgroundColor]` and with all of my code's backgroundColor properties referencing this single object in memory I could then simply change the properties on that object and the appearance of the app would reflect that change.  However, the changes don't reflect.  That fact can be reduced to this code:

```
   UIColor *someUIColorObject = [UIColor redColor];
   self.view.backgroundColor = someUIColorObject;

   someUIColorObject= [UIColor yellowColor];
```

in which, according to my initial assumption, self.view would appear yellow, but rather it appears red.  My understanding of OOP, reference types, and pointers in general was that if something is pointing to a value and you update that value than anything pointing to the pointer should see the new value.  Obviously, some other factor is obviating that theory.  Perhaps some view related behavior concerning drawing or the run loop, or perhaps under the hood view.backgroundColor makes a copy of the uicolor object when setting it.

Anyway, this peeked my curiosity, and at the very least could be a good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about pointers, but in this case there is another issue. If you look at the definition of `backgroundColor` property in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor) you will see that it is defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor
```

And what `copy` does is it actually copies the color and stores it in the `backgroundColor` property.

So, rather than pointing to the original pointer which you were assigning, it creates a new instance and points to that new instance.

Comment: Thank you.  That was one of my candidate theories but I forgot about looking in the header files to verify it.  That being the case, do you know a clear way of reclaiming my Theme Singleton class concept?  So that by updating its various properties the app's look and feel would update in mass?

Comment: @AlexanderBollbach this is an interesting question. In my apps I usually rely on NSNotifications to update the color theme. You may try to create an array inside of your singleton where you store all assignments which were made using blocks. You will have to move the color assignments to a separate function which will create a block to be executed. I am not sure if this will work, but if you store those blocks then after your theme changes you can re-execute them. You need to be careful though as some views might be nil because they got released, so you should check for that in your blocks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by storing the assignments with blocks?  I was thinking about creating references to each "style" element within the singleton and then a method to iterate through the references and make assignments on their backgroundColor, borderWidth, properties.. etc..  Is that similar to what you mean?